# Open UserControl as a popup

Tags: vb.net

I have a grid view in aspx page with a column of hyperlinks. On click of hyperlink of a particular row, I want an ascx to be opened.Parameters has to be passed from aspx to ascx as properties. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hai, Aswathy have you tried anything?

Comment: Show your effort so far !!